# using uniform_real_distribution in C++

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to use uniform_real_distribution in C++ to generate an array of random numbers. Here is my code

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int max_index = 48655;
    vector<int> arr;
    arr.resize(100);

    std::random_device radm;
    std::mt19937_64 mt(radm());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> distribution(0, max_index);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = int(distribution(mt)*(max_index-1))%(max_index-1);
    }
    return 0
}
```

The problem is, although I have explicitly specified that the random number is uniform distributed within `0` and `max_index`, there are still some negative numbers in my array. And their values are the same `(-2432)`.

May I know what am I wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT1:

===================================================================

I'm afraid that many of the repliers are struggling with the multiplication and modulo operation. This was a mistake, that I've already deleted it. **But the point is, even this could semantically affect the results, it cannot make the generator give negative results.**

Comment: Are you sure you're validating the contents of your vector correctly? It doesn't look like your code could ever produce a negative number on systems with a 32-bit `int` (which I assume is what you have.) Btw, what purpose do the multiplication and modulus serve?

Comment: The most important question is why are you doing that multiplication and modulus on the value in your loop? What is the range of values you need and why don't you just specify that in the distribution and be done with it?

Comment: @Blastfurnace That was a mistake. I deleted it since I don't need to control the range any more. Anyway, the point is why there are negative values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `(max_index-1)**2 = 2367211716 > 2**31 - 1`.  Any value larger than 44136 will cause overflow of a signed int when you multiply it by `max_index-1`. That's about 9% of random numbers you're generating.

Do your arithmetic with longs until after the modulo operation to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

all

Thanks for your answers. I do really appreciate.

Now, I've made a little change to my code as follows

```
ind[i] = abs(int(distribution(mt)));
```

In this case, there is no more negative values appear.

However, the question still remains unanswered: WHY THERE ARE NEGATIVES IN 1ST POST?

Comment: Do you really need abs?

Comment: In the loop you can print distribution(mt) if (int)(distribution(mt)*(max_index-1)) < 0. This can help you answering...

Comment: Try: 
double myValue = distribution(mt); 
if ((int(myValue*(max_index-1))%(max_index-1) ) < 0)
    std::cout << myValue << " " << myValue*(max_index-1) << " " (int(myValue*(max_index-1)) << " " << int(myValue*(max_index-1))%(max_index-1) << std::endl; 

Your question is worth investigating...